# Update All SQL Server Databases By Edit Only One Database

Tags: sql-server

Can i made a database like "model database" but not only for new databases, but for old databases also, to allow me to edit only one database, then edits happened to all databases in server.

My Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The implementation of such a feature would be hugely complex. What if one or more of the databases that would be affected by the addition of a new table already has a table with that same name?

What if one of the databases has added a new column to one of the "shared" tables? Should a change to the "sort of like model" database overwrite that column? Or ignore it?

There are so many complex issues to deal with here, and most of them would end up having to be answered on an individual basis (i.e. what works for you doesn't work for me, or vice versa).

---

On the other hand, if you're dealing with a set of common tables, with common data, where those tables should only have one "shape", you might want to look into [Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx):

> Replication is a set of technologies for copying and distributing data and database objects from one database to another and then synchronizing between databases to maintain consistency. Using replication, you can distribute data to different locations and to remote or mobile users over local and wide area networks, dial-up connections, wireless connections, and the Internet.